# Reference to array of objects in Sanity

Tags: sanity

Im having issues with references in Sanity. Im setting some color themes in the root of my Sanity schema:

```
defineField({
      name: 'articletheme',
      title: 'Article theme',
      description: 'Create 4 themes for article blocks',
      type: 'array',
      validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
      of: [{ type: 'articleThemeBlock' }],
    }),
```

In one of the blocks I would like to reference the theme array to select which color theme that block should use.

Ive tried this, but it fails:

```
defineField({
      name: 'theme',
      title: 'Theme',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [
        {
          type: 'array',
          of: [
            {
              type: 'articletheme',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }),
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing but the your second schema above looks incorrect, try this -

```
defineField({
  name: 'theme',
  title: 'Theme',
  type: 'array',  // changed from reference to array
  to: [
    {
      type: 'reference',  // changed from array to reference
      of: [
        {
          type: 'articletheme',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, type array, an array OF reference, referencing TO type articletheme
`

```
defineField({
  name: 'theme',
  title: 'Theme',
  type: 'array',  // changed from reference to array
  of: [
    {
      type: 'reference',  // changed from array to reference
      to: [
        {
          type: 'articletheme',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}),
```

`